# C# Bills Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

[image: Screen shot]

So as a personal project (I'm still really new) for my wife, I was tasked with the project of making a program to keep track of bills. Attached is the windows form with the requested information. So, I am pretty sure I will be able to get the end part of this figured out. However, I'm having a really hard time how to assign the values to a specific date of the calendar. She's wanting to be able to select a date, and the rest of the week highlight, then add up the days of that week, and provide the requested info.

As of right now, I just have the different bills as ints set to their amount owed. So I don't have much code to be corrected. If I can't use the .net calendar, and I have to create my own, I will. I'm just not sure if I could save time and use the .net one.

Comment: See codeproject.com.  There have a bunch of custom calendars.  I usually search google for : codeproject c# custom calendar

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly you're asking for. Is it just a UI component that you're looking for, or the logic to work with the dates afterwards?

Comment: I have the UI as shown above, my main obstacle right now is figuring out how to associate the bills with the actual dates so that it knows which ones to add together for the week requested.